# Julia: How to find a list of the elements of a Composite Type

Tags: mathematical-optimization, julia

Let's say we are using the rosenbrock function in the [Optim package](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Optim.jl) designed by John Myles White.  Could someone tell me where I would find the attributes/methods returned from this function?

```
f(x)=(1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2
a=optimize(f, [0.0, 0.0])
attributes(a)
```

I am primarily interested in grabbing the optimized values to create a distribution of values to test for bias, approximate standard errors (in a data sample with a estimated statistics), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the following by delving into how White created the [benchmarks](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Optim.jl/blob/master/benchmarks/adfd.jl) for the package.

```
>a.minimum
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
1.00001
1.00001
```

I have also found

```
>a.iterations
60
```

However, reading over [Composite Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1) again I am still not sure how to find the list of elements of composite types.

Comment: I think you are looking for `names(a)` for the fields and `methodswith(typeof(a))` for methods.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!  Arg, it is the obvious words which are so easily missed.